# How to capture all error events in react native webview in ios?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-webview-bridge library to render a webview inside my react native Ios app. I am trying to implement an offline reader app, where I need to capture all the error events when the `webview` fails to load images, so that from react native when I capture the event I can send local images as fallback source to the image in webview.

Answer (score 2):

Function that is invoked when the `WebView` load fails is **onError: PropTypes.func,**. Pass this into WebView like this:-

```
<WebView
                ref={o => (this.webView = o)}
                source={{ uri: this.state.uri }}
                style={styles.webView.style}
                renderError={() => this.Spinner.showOffline(true)}
                onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart.bind(this)}
                onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd.bind(this)}
                onError={()=>console.warn('error')}
            />
```

and open your react-native WebView.android.js or WebView.iOS.js file.

Comment: This is not working. May be because the webview is loading with other content like text. It's only for images that an api call is being made and is failing to load the images. I need to capture error events from the webview dom not the load error of the webview itself